# Why does the app crash whenever I try to add elements of data class to RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, gson, sharedpreferences

I am learning how to use kotlin for a University assignment and we need to save a data class using GSON and converting the data class into a string and saving the string using sharedPreferences. After calling back the saved object, when I try to pass the data to the recyclerview the app crashes.

This is where the object is saved

```
package com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.security.spec.PSSParameterSpec
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.util.*
import kotlin.random.Random


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val dateTime = Calendar.getInstance().time

        val dateFormatted = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(dateTime)

        val dateTextView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.textDate) as TextView
        dateTextView.setText(dateFormatted)
        }


    fun secondActivity(view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this, passwords::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    fun randomise(view: View){


        val passwordSet1 = Random.nextInt(0,99)
        val passwordSet2 = Random.nextInt(0,99)
        val passwordSet3 = Random.nextInt(0,99)
        val passwordSet4 = Random.nextInt(0,99)

        val editText1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password1)
        editText1.setText(passwordSet1.toString())

        val editText2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password2)
        editText2.setText(passwordSet2.toString())

        val editText3 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password3)
        editText3.setText(passwordSet3.toString())

        val editText4 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password4)
        editText4.setText(passwordSet4.toString())

    }



    fun save(view: View){

        val sharedPrefsCounter = getSharedPreferences("passwordAppCounter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var i = sharedPrefsCounter.getInt("counter", 0)

        if (i == 0){
            val editorCounter = sharedPrefsCounter.edit()

            editorCounter.putInt("counter", 1)
            editorCounter.apply()

            i = 1
        }


        val dateTime = Calendar.getInstance().time

        val dateFormatted = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(dateTime)


        val description = descriptionName.text.toString().trim()
        val password = password1.text.toString().trim() + "-" + password2.text.toString().trim() + "-" + password3.text.toString().trim() + "-" + password4.text.toString().trim()
        if (description == "" || password == "---"){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter Proper Value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            val date = dateTime.toString()

            val data = PasswordCluster(description, password, date)
            val jsonPassword = Gson().toJson(data)


            val sharedPrefsPasswords =
                getSharedPreferences("passwordAppPasswords", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val editorPassword = sharedPrefsPasswords.edit()

            editorPassword.putString("passwordObject" + i, jsonPassword)

            editorPassword.apply()

            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            val editorCounter = sharedPrefsCounter.edit()

            editorCounter.putInt("counter", i + 1)
            editorCounter.apply()


        }


    }

}
```

This is where the saved string is called again to be used

```
package com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.ScrollView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class passwords : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_passwords)

        val dateTime = Calendar.getInstance().time

        val dateFormatted = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(dateTime)

        val dateTextView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.textDate2) as TextView
        dateTextView.setText(dateFormatted)

        val sharedPrefsCounter = getSharedPreferences("passwordAppCounter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val counter = sharedPrefsCounter.getInt("counter", 0)

        val recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.savedPasswords) as RecyclerView

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)

        var passwords = ArrayList<PasswordCluster>()

        if (counter > 0) {

            val sharedPrefsPass = getSharedPreferences("passwordAppPasswords", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

            for (i in 1..counter) {

                var objectString = sharedPrefsPass.getString("passwordObject" + counter, "")

                var passwordObject = Gson().fromJson<PasswordCluster>(objectString, PasswordCluster::class.java!!)

                passwords.add(PasswordCluster(passwordObject.description, passwordObject.passwordCluster, passwordObject.dateTime))
            }
        }

        val adapter = CustomAdapter(passwords)

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    }

    fun firstActivity(view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

This is the data class

```
package com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1

data class PasswordCluster(var description: String, var passwordCluster: String, var dateTime: String)
```

And this is the error when I try to run the activity that pastes the object data

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1, PID: 24773
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1/com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1.passwords}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1.PasswordCluster.getDescription()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1.PasswordCluster.getDescription()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.juliaojonah_hci_outcome2_v1.passwords.onCreate(passwords.kt:52)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I checked the sharedPreferences and the file does exist, so I don't understand why it is saying it's null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `objectString` you get from a SharedPreference has a default value of an empty string. So if the shared preference you try to retrieve doesn't exist yet, you pass `""` to `Gson.fromJson()`. Then it returns null because it can't parse it to anything.

Since Gson is a Java library, Kotlin doesn't enforce null safety on the returned value.

Comment: How would I make sure that it isn't null then? Is pulling the object from the shared preferences not working correctly?

Comment: Maybe you could change it to `""` if it is null. I seem to remember that if you store an empty String preference, when you retrieve it later it is null. Since it exists already, you get null instead of the default value you pass to `getString()`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I didn't realise fixing that would just fix everything.

Comment: I converted a test version of a data class to a json string and passed that as the default value. That fixed everything